# How do you set up Orchard CMS with a MySQL database instead of a MS SQL one?

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

What exactly do you need to modify in Orchard CMS to make it use a MySQL database for it's storage instead of a MS SQL database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use MySQL database with Orchard CMS 1.3.10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701008/how-to-use-mysql-database-with-orchard-cms-1-3-10)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Although the titles are very similar, the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701008/how-to-use-mysql-database-with-orchard-cms-1-3-10 is a question about a detail quite far down the line of using MySQL with a specific, old version of Orchard - it doesn't help anyone starting out with it which is what I need. (It doesn't have any answers for that title, which differs from the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this fork: http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/RickardP/orchardmysql